# Mysql select records from 2 rows

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table include some data like that. This is example for question/answer script. ID is auto increment and if PID=0 then it is question, when reply any question then PID is set to question's ID. There is no Subject for replies.

```
ID    PID    SUBJECT                CONTENT                   DATE
1      0     First Question         This is my first          09/01/2013
2      0     Second Question        This is second            09/01/2013
3      1                            Yes this is first         09/01/2013
4      2                            I agree this is second    10/01/2013
5      0     Third Question         This is third question    11/01/2013
6      1                            Reply to first            11/01/2013
7      1                            Another reply to first    12/01/2013
8      5                            This is reply of 5th      13/01/2013
9      2                            Last try for second       14/01/2013
```

My questions are,

How can I select questions with reply count?

```
Ex.
First Question (3)
Second Question (2)
Third Question (1)
```

How can I select today's answered questions or answers?

```
Ex. For 09/01/2013
First Question (2) ---> 1 question and 1 answer but 2 actions
Second Question (1) ---> just 1 question
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try join for first task

```
SELECT 
    q.id as ID,
    q.pid as PID,
    q.subject as SUBJECT,
    COUNT(lq.id) as Total
FROM questions as q
LEFT JOIN questions as lq ON lq.pid = q.ID
WHERE q.PID = 0
GROUP BY q.id
```

OUTPUT

```
ID  PID     SUBJECT             TOTAL
1   0       First Question      3
2   0       Second Question     2
5   0       Third Question      1
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fa73/22)

EDITS :
For second part. You should note that there can be many other ways for doing the same task.

```
SELECT 
    q.id as ID,
    q.pid as PID,
    q.subject as SUBJECT,
    (COUNT(lq.id) - 1) as Total,
    q.date
FROM questions as q
LEFT JOIN questions as lq ON lq.pid = q.ID OR lq.id = q.PID
WHERE q.date = DATE(NOW())
```

OUTPUT

```
ID  PID     SUBJECT             TOTAL   DATE
1   0       First Question      2       January, 09 2012 00:00:00+0000
2   0       Second Question     1       January, 09 2012 00:00:00+0000
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3fa73/19)

Answer (score 1):

Select the questions and join against the answers:

```
select q.id, q.subject, count(a.id)
from yourtable q
left join yourtable a on q.id=a.pid
where q.pid=0
group by q.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, so how can I do that for today's questions?

Comment: @Seyhan: add `and q.date=curdate()` to the where clause (assuming your date column is actually of date type)

Answer (score 0):

For question 1

```
select PID,count(*) from table
where pid<>0 
group by PID
```

For question 2

```
select PID,count(*) from table
where pid<>0 and date=current_date()
group by PID
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I want